# Bearer token is checked even if endpoint is set to permitAll

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using `spring-security-oauth2-provider:3.0.0-RC2` with Grails `3.2.1`. All of the resource endpoints starts with `/api` using

```
"/api/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?" {
    constraints {
    }
}
```

And here is the filter chain map (same as given in the docs):

```
String tokenFilters = "JOINED_FILTERS,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter"
String securedResourcesFilter = "JOINED_FILTERS,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-oauth2BasicAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter"
String otherFilters = "JOINED_FILTERS,-statelessSecurityContextPersistenceFilter,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter,-oauth2BasicAuthenticationFilter,-oauth2ExceptionTranslationFilter"

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        [pattern: "/api/oauth/token", filters: tokenFilters],
        [pattern: "/api/**", filters: securedResourcesFilter],
        [pattern: "/**", filters: otherFilters]
]
```

I'm using password grant authentication and everything is working fine by passing `Authorization` header whenever the token is available in the browser's local storage.

I'm storing the bearer token in the browser's local storage. The problem is when the token is expired and still available in the browser's local storage. One of the action is marked as `@Secured(["permitAll"])` so when I'm hitting that action (and the expired `Authorization` header is also passed), the request is being denied with 401 since the token is expired.

Is this by design that even if an endpoint or controller/action is set to `permitAll`, the spring security will still check for validity of access token if it is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe the `401` response is by design.

What you are describing is the behavior of the `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`.  The filter [attempts to extract the token from the request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2.0.11.RELEASE/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/authentication/OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java#L131) and upon finding one it [attempts to authenticate it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2.0.11.RELEASE/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/authentication/OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java#L150).  If the authentication fails for some reason (like an expired token), [the filter will treat it as an Authentication failure](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2.0.11.RELEASE/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/authentication/OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java#L161).

Because the `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` is in a high position in the filter-chain it terminates the request upon an invalid token before the request has a chance to go to a lower level and make decisions based on controller annotations.

Basically, If you present an access token, the application will attempt to authenticate it.

### Workarounds

When you obtain an access token from spring-security-oauth2-provider, it typically contains some expiration information that could be checked in the client to prevent the expired Authorization header from being sent in the first place.  You might also look into using the [Refresh Token Grant](http://bluesliverx.github.io/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider/v3/manual/guide/exampleFlows.html#refreshToken).

If changing the client doesn't work you could configure the `filterChain.chainMap` so that the uri of the controller action which you are attempting to allow uses the `otherFilters` like this:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    [pattern: "/api/oauth/token", filters: tokenFilters],
    [pattern: "/api/foo/myControllerActionThatIsPermitAll", filters: otherFilters],
    [pattern: "/api/**", filters: securedResourcesFilter],
    [pattern: "/**", filters: otherFilters]
]
```

Please note that there is [a github issue reported on spring-security-oauth](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/723) that describes your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Colin. I was looking for this only. That was my main concern if that is implementation by default or a problem.